# Let grid use all available space?

Tags: css, alignment, grid-layout

I'm currently making a web application where you'll have 3 boards (similar to a board game) that will be filled with tiles as the game progresses.

[The current state of my Web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3lUZ.png)

For this, I've decided to use `grid` to align all the boards, but I would like my grid to use **all available space**. I do have already a bottom bar that uses `position: fixed` and a top bar that uses `flex`.

I've tried adjusting the height already, but this didn't work.

Here's the relevant code for it:

```css
main{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 60% 20% 20%;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    grid-template-areas: "playerBoard moneyBoard marketBoard";
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.tileBoard{
    display: grid;
    grid-column-start: 1;
}
.moneyBoard{
    display: grid;
    grid-column-start: 2;
}
.marketBoard{
    display: grid;
    grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="tileBoard">
        <p>Start Tile</p>
    </div>
    <div class="moneyBoard">
        <h2>Money</h2>
        <h2>Money</h2>
        <h2>Money</h2>
        <h2>Money</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="marketBoard">
        <h3>Buyable Tile 1</h3>
        <h3>Buyable Tile 2</h3>
        <h3>Buyable Tile 3</h3>
        <h3>Buyable Tile 4</h3>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: what is your definition on 'all available space'? It seems it already spreads out nicely horizontally... you need ik to fill vertically as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added CSS rules for `html`, `body`, and `main` elements. These rules make them occupy the full height of the page. Does this solve your problem?

```css
/* Added */
html {height: 100%}

/* Added */
body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
}

main{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 60% 20% 20%;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
    grid-template-areas: "playerBoard moneyBoard marketBoard";
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
 min-height: 100%; /* Added */
}

.tileBoard{
    display: grid;
    grid-column-start: 1;
}
.moneyBoard{
    display: grid;
    grid-column-start: 2;
}
.marketBoard{
    display: grid;
    grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="tileBoard">
        <p>Start Tile</p>
    </div>
    <div class="moneyBoard">
        <h2>Money</h2>
        <h2>Money</h2>
        <h2>Money</h2>
        <h2>Money</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="marketBoard">
        <h3>Buyable Tile 1</h3>
        <h3>Buyable Tile 2</h3>
        <h3>Buyable Tile 3</h3>
        <h3>Buyable Tile 4</h3>
    </div>
</main>
```